# JFrame Form - Java returned: 1 | BUILD FAILED

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I'm trying to make a traffic light in Java but when I start my application I see black screen and when the execution ends, java gives me this error: "Java returned: 1".
Only when the for cycle ends the traffic light is loaded but in any case I receive the error mentioned above.
Here is the code of the panel (which contains the traffic light) that I put in the form.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TrafficlightPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener{

    public void waitTime(long time){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(time);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { 

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(5, 5, 60, 160);

        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.fillOval(15, 15, 40, 40);
        g.fillOval(15, 65, 40, 40);
        g.fillOval(15, 115, 40, 40);

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g.fillOval(15, 115, 40, 40);

            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillOval(15, 15, 40, 40);

            waitTime(3000);

            g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g.fillOval(15, 15, 40, 40);

            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g.fillOval(15, 65, 40, 40);

            waitTime(1500);

            g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g.fillOval(15, 65, 40, 40);

            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillOval(15, 115, 40, 40);

            waitTime(3000);

        }
    }
}
```

Can you please help me? Thank you and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

```
Java returned: 1
```

This would be for only two cases either you have an error with your unshown code or you have used `System.exit(int status)`, with status  `1`.

> Only when the for cycle ends the traffic light is loaded

That would be because your whole code is in the for loop.

I guess that you have your problem in the `wait(long time)` method
and you should use swing worker instead of sleeping swings threads as they are considered unsafe threads